# Hide navigation bar ios swift life cycle methods not called causing issues

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, viewwillappear

I want to hide navigation bar in a particular view controller in my TabBarController

Following is code in my first view controller of tabbar

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
 }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

}
```

But sometimes when I change tabbar selection viewWillAppear is not called also if I present view from this controller viewWillAppear is not called on dismissal of presented controller.

Due to which facing issues. how to fix this?

Also viewWillDisappear is not called if I push a view controller following is code for it

```
    let flightVC = AppStrings.appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "flightViewPagerControllerID") as! FlightViewPagerController



    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(flightVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `viewWillAppear` not firing when the tab bar selection changes, I think it's better to override `optional func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)` and hide/unhide based on your viewController.

In case of `viewWillAppear` not being called on dismissal of presented controller, make sure your `modalPresentationStyle` is set to `.fullScreen`

**Edit**: As per the updated question I think you should either use `navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)` or `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` for detecting whether a view has been pushed.

Comment: hi updated question facing issue on push view controller as well

Comment: @amodkanthe Updated answer based on the details